# How to define validation constraints on TextFields in vaadin?

Tags: java, validation, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a `TextField` and add validation by `field.addValidator(validator)`.
I want to use the field both for editing an entity, as well as creating a new one.

Problem: when creating a new one, I would like to have more validators applied then when editing. Eg: creating an Account  would require a `UniqueAccountValidator` added to the textfield.

But then, when I editing the account (with the same form), I'd like to skip only the `UniqueAccountValidator` as the object is not be be created new, but merged.

Is is possible to somehow tell a vaadin `BeanFieldGroup` or an `AbstractField` to skip certain validators in specific cases?

Comment: can't you use two different command objects/models for this case? if the validator is in the field it will be used.

Comment: Yes of course, but I'd like to reuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own custom validator by implementing the Validator interface. There you can check what you need, like whether the entity is a new one or not.

Something like

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value) {
        //check if your object is new or existent
        if(((BeanObject)value).getID()==null)){
        //non-existent entity, also check the unique account constraint 
             if(accountExists()) {
                   return false;
             }
             else {
                   return true;
             }
         }

         //common checks....
         {....} 

    }
....
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea, probably better than constantly adding/removing the validator on the field.